# '' get'' and '' go'' with means of transport

Tags: word-usage, difference

- I've looked up the difference between '' go'' and ''get'' + means of transport and found out that both are used. Then there is a native speaker saying that '' I get to work by car'' is a passive sentence and it sounds odd. If someone drives me to work, which sentence sounds more natural? ''I go to work by car'' or '' I get to work by car''?  What's the difference between ''get'' and ''go'' when these words combine with means of transport?

I'd really appreciate your answering my question!!

Comment: You're asking three questions. Please ask only one, and take the tour.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I've edited the post.  :)

Comment: "go" vs. "get" here is a minor distinction. "get" focuses" a little more on the means by which you arrive at work, rather than the travel itself. Given that, my rule is don't use "get" if there is another word to use in its place, that will get across the meaning you want better.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing up my doubts!! @user3169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that "I go to work by car" is what I would expect to hear when someone is describing a habitual action, however, "I get to work by car" makes a particular emphasis on the way you *get* to work, that being by car.

Comment: Thank you so much @Riolku!!